# trying to load data from a website into json file

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to load data from a website into a json file.

> > > when i try this code, nothing is wrong:

```
import requests
import json

url="https://leoclub-ssmc.blogspot.com/?m=1"

r=requests.get(url)
print(r.text)
```

> > > this code above show  the web's full page with html code without error.
> > >
> > > but when i try to load all the code into a json file then it shows some error message

```
import requests
import json

url="https://leoclub-ssmc.blogspot.com/?m=1"

r=requests.get(url)
print(r.json)
```

this above code show:
bound method Response.json of  Response [200]
[Program finished]

> > > moving on::

```
import requests
import json

url="https://leoclub-ssmc.blogspot.com/?m=1"

r=requests.get(url).json()
print(r)
```

★★now this show this error message: ""raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)""
[Program finished]

i just want to load data in json file and then to show them specifically in my app

Comment: Its an html page, not json. After `r=requests.get(url)` you could `print(r.headers["Content-Type"])` and it will print `text/html`.

Comment: thanks for your desire to help me. but did you read my full post? i added more codes below.  r=requests.get(url).json()   by using this can i access data in a json file?

Comment: i posted 3 different codes. you are talking about the 1st code.  please see last two codes

Comment: I read your post and ran your code. That url returns html, not json. You could scrape the page and build a python list or dict and then convert that to json if you'd like. But the python json decoder just decodes json, nothing else.

Comment: Here is what you asked for: _i just want to load data in json file and then to show them specifically in my app_

Answer (score 3):

The third method you use is correct:

```
r = requests.get(url).json()
```

However this page doesn't actually return JSON hence the `JSONDecodeError`.

If you wish the scrape the page, and get that data into a Python datastructure, or JSON, you should probably investiate libraries like `BeautifulSoup4` or `Selenium` which are used for web-scraping.

Comment: so, i cant get data from some particular site(like this site im trying) using request? hence i should use beautifulsoup4? im i right?

Comment: the `requests` library just allows you to make a request to a server, and get the data back.  If the URL you query happens to return valid JSON, you can use the `Response.json()` method to convert this to a python datastructure.  If that URL doesn't return JSON, you'd need to parse it somehow (bs4/selenium) to get it into a python datastructure. In your first example `r.text` contains the HTML, so you could probably pass that into bs4.

Answer (score 1):

The website that you are trying to read doesn't contain JSON data. 
Try with this website: url="http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA"

If you are trying to parse an HTML file check BeautifulSoup api.